# Unflatten a database record into Master/Detail in EF 5 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a legacy database table that has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MASTER_PROJECT](
    [DATA_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ......
    [GENRE_DATA_ID] [bigint] NULL,  
    [ADDITIONAL_GENRE_DATA_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ADDITIONAL_GENRE_2_DATA_ID] [bigint] NULL )
```

I want to have the following classes mapped out using EF 5 (code first)

```
public class Project {
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Genre> Genres {get;set;}
}

public class Genre {
   public long Id {get;set;}
   // other stuff
}
```

At first I tried making Genres an array and mapping like this

```
    HasOptional(t => t.Genres[0]).WithOptionalDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("GENRE_DATA_ID"));
    HasOptional(t => t.Genres[1]).WithOptionalDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("ADDITIONAL_GENRE_DATA_ID"));
    HasOptional(t => t.Genres[2]).WithOptionalDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("ADDITIONAL_GENRE_2_DATA_ID"));
```

But this generates an error, that t.Genres[0] is not a valid property. (Which makes sense)

Any idea on how would I go about doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Moho, here is how I finally got what I wanted.

Also you need to make sure that the project that houses this domain entity grants internals visible to the mapping project. (In the AssemblyInfo.cs)

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YOUR.MAPPING.PROJECT")]
```

Entity definition

```
public class Project 
{
        private ObservableCollection<Genre> _genres;
        protected internal virtual Genre Genre1 { get; set; }
        protected internal virtual Genre Genre2 { get; set; }
        protected internal virtual Genre Genre3 { get; set; }

        public IList<Genre> Genres
        {
            get
            {
                if (_genres == null)
                {
                    _genres = new ObservableCollection<Genre>(new[] {Genre1, Genre2, Genre3});
                    _genres.CollectionChanged += GenresCollectionChangedHandler;
                }
                return _genres;
            }
        }
        private void SetGenreByIndex(int index, Genre g)
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: Genre1 = g; break;
                case 1: Genre2 = g; break;
                case 2: Genre3 = g; break;
            }
        }

        private void GenresCollectionChangedHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {                
            _genres.CollectionChanged -= GenresCollectionChangedHandler;

            int max = 3;
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    if (_genres.Count > max)
                    {
                        _genres.RemoveAt(max);
                        _genres.CollectionChanged += GenresCollectionChangedHandler;
                        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Not allowed to store more than 3 genres.");
                    }
                    SetGenreByIndex(_genres.Count - 1, e.NewItems[0] as Genre);
                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        SetGenreByIndex(i + e.NewStartingIndex, e.NewItems[i] as Genre);
                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    Genre1 = null;
                    Genre2 = null;
                    Genre3 = null;
                    _genres.Clear();
                    break;
            }
            _genres.CollectionChanged += GenresCollectionChangedHandler;
        }
}
```

Here is the Code First Mapping class

```
public class ProjectConfiguration
{
    public ProjectConfiguration()
    {
        // ...
        // GENRES collection
        Ignore(t => t.Genres);
        HasOptional(t => t.Genre1).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("GENRE_DATA_ID"));
        HasOptional(t => t.Genre2).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("GENRE_DATA_ID_1"));
        HasOptional(t => t.Genre3).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("GENRE_DATA_ID_2"));
    }
}
```

And here is a test method to ensure it works

```
[TestClass]
public class ProjectUnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SwapGenresInListAndSaveTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        Genre original1 = null;
        Genre original2 = null;

        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

            //ACT
            var project = context.Projects.Find(2341);
            original1 = project.Genres[0];
            original2 = project.Genres[1];

            genres[0] = original2;
            genres[1] = original1;

            //Save to DB
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //ASSERT
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var project1 = context.Projects.Find(2341);

            //ASSERT
            Assert.IsNotNull(project1);
            Assert.IsNotNull(project1.Genres);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, project1.Genres.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(original2.DataId, project1.Genres[0].DataId);
            Assert.AreEqual(original1.DataId, project1.Genres[1].DataId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do has nothing to do with EF - you need to implement a partial class of this entity with a new method or property that returns a collection of the items.  You will, of course, need to populate this collection with the values in the various genre data ID properties.  For example:

```
public ICollection<Genre?> GenreDataIDs
{
    get 
    {
        var col = new List<Genre?>() { GENRE_DATA_ID_NavProperty, ADDITIONAL_GENRE_DATA_ID_NavProperty, ..., ADDITION_GENRE_N_DATA_ID_NavProperty };

        return col;
    }
}
```

Your navigation properties are probably named something like Genre1, Genre2; I've simply added _NavProperty to the column name for illustrative purposes.

If you want to use the collection to update the underlying DB record, it would get more complex (easiest implementation would be to implement a SetGenreDataID( int index, int? value ) method )

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still not sure I understand what you are getting at.
Are you saying add a property GenreDataIDs to the main Project class? Then how would I go about mapping those DataIDs to the associated mapped Genre classes?

Comment: Instead of a list of int? you can return List<GENRE?>; same principle, which is you must construct ICollection yourself.  I'll edit the answer

Comment: Ok, I see what you are getting at. So Project will have 4 public properties, Genre1, Genre2, Genre3, and IList<Genre>Genres. That was what I was trying to avoid, but I guess there is no way around that.
Thank you for help!